# Compiling for Multiple Targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile my program both to linux and windows using g++ and mingw respectively. The only difference between the compilations is the compiler to use and output file name.

A single `make` command should produce both output files. What is the best way to achieve this with as little duplications in the makefile as possible?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
linux-name: CC:=g++
windows-name: CC:=mingw

linux-name windows-name:
    $(CC) whatever -o $@
```

**EDIT:**

What I wrote above is only the *new* part of the makefile; I assumed that the rest of the makefile was implied. To be more explicit:

```
all: linux-name windows-name

linux-name: CC:=g++
windows-name: CC:=mingw

linux-name windows-name: foo.o bar.o baz.o SomethingElse
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) whatever $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIR) whatever -c $< -o $@

SomethingElse:
    build somehow
```

Comment: I did not know that it is possible to put two target names like this. Unfortunately it does not work for me, only linux-name is built. Also what can I do if I have dependent target that require compilation as well?

Comment: Now after you edit I see that my first try did not work because a mistake I did, I put my definition of 'all' target after the 'linux-name' and 'windows-name' targets. Yet, there is still problem with your solution, the object files are compiled only once, in your example they will be only compiled for linux. When make will execute windows-name target, the object files are already present and it will not recompile them.

Comment: There are several ways to solve that problem; you must make a design decision. What do you want Make to do?

Comment: I want make to produce two files compiled for different platforms.

Comment: @Artium: two files? or 2n files? *What do you want Make to do about the object files?* Do you want all object files rebuilt when you build the other executable? Do you want two sets of object files, one for each system? If so, do you want them distinguished by filename, or kept in different directories? Or is it satisfactory to delete all object files after each build?

Comment: Two sets of object files distinguished by file name or different directories (does not matter). This is best option as I don't want to rebuild all code base in each build.